# TCL EXPECT - Enter password with printing to stdout and assign in to a variable

Tags: tcl, expect

I currently have a TCL expect script that connects to multiple devices via SSH. Ivee used a for loop to reiterate through the devices.

My problem is that the actual password is defined as a variable in the script in plain text. My password for all devices are the same since we are using TACACS.

What I want to happen is that when I type my password, there is no STDOUT and when I press ENTER it will assign it to a variable that my script can use.

heres an example of my script:

```
set userName "me"
set host "192.168.1.1"

puts "Enter password: "
gets stdin passWord
spawn ssh $userName\@$host
expect "*word: "
send "$passWord\r"
expect "#"
send "term len 0\r"
expect "#"
send "show ip int br\r"
expect "#"
```

Thanks!

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: I want to type my password in the terminal but it shouldnt show it in stdout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `stty` command:

```
stty -echo
# there is no echo in terminal
#

stty echo
# return echo back
```